# UIImagePickerController crash on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

```
UIImagePickerController *ii_picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
ii_picker.delegate=self;
ii_picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
add_photo=NO;
[self presentModalViewController:ii_picker animated:YES];
[ii_picker release];
```

This used to work fine till I updated to iOS 5 on my iPhone. Something strange...

Problem isn't in the code. It's working in blank project! If I paste it to any place in my project's code, it's crashing. If I change `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`, it's working in iOS5.

Does anybody know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app crashes as below, need to change the app's product name in English.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1m6f.png]

In my case product name was written in Korean, this led to the crash in ios5 when UIImagePickerController's source type is UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.

Answer (score 1):

If app is crashes in iOS 5 , then try to use

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 picker = nil ;
```

In place of 
            `[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          [picker release];`

Answer (score -1):

Note, on the simulator, there's no camera, so it could cause this.

Comment: Ah, such negativity. Sometimes the simplest solution is the right one. Though I should have left this as a comment I realize.